# В MS Visual C++ есть Application, а что есть под linux?

Tags: g++, gui, c++, linux

В MS Visual C++ есть Application, а что есть под linux?
хочу писать GUI под Linux, но Qt и GTK+ учить трудно-существуют ли программы для создания графичексого интерфейса?

Comment: Напиши на Java. Если знаешь С++, то переход на Java не вызовет трудностей.

Comment: Есть такая незаслуженно забыта штуковина tcl/Tk. При желании встраивается в Си, а можно работать через pty.

Comment: Трудно учить? Программирование вообще штука непростая.

Comment: какой visual studio? <b>gedit</b> наше все ^^ !!!

Comment: Точно. Или vim - по вкусу.

Comment: я знаю, что это штука трудная.
также использую gedit.
также не оценил java.
также пытался совмещать pty программы для вызова своих программ через систему, но Tk не такой красивый как хотелось бы...

Comment: А еще он хорошо в питоне реализован

Comment: Кто он? Tk (Tkinter), Gtk, Qt, wxWindows?

Comment: @alexlz Tcl/Tk, Хотя gtk тоже неплохо реализован. Про другие сказать не могу, т.к. не знаю

Comment: "Реализован" -- неправильное слово. Реализованы они на C, а в питоне -- "биндинги", т.е. промежуточный слой между библиотеками виджетов и питоном. Причём в случае Tkinter -- связь действительно не только с графикой Tk, но и с Tcl-интерпретатором. (Иной подход -- PerlTk, где от tcl только смутные следы)

Answer (score 3):

Под `unix`-подобные системы выбор средства зависит от используемой оболочки.

*Общая схема используемых библиотек такова:*

- В `GNOME`: `libcairo` -> `GTK`
- В `KDE`: `Qt`

Т.к создатели `KDE` и `GNOME` тоже не дураки, то программы, написанные на `GTK` и `Qt` вполне могут заменяться и нормально работать под `KDE` и `GNOME` соответственно.

Отсюда вывод - можно брать любую из них и работать над созданием своего оконного интерфейса. Однако, заставить приложение, написанное на `GTK`, более-менее адекватно выглядеть и работать под `Windows` сложнее, нежели приложение, написанное на `Qt.`

*Т.е для создания кросс-платформенного приложения стоит, наверно, все-таки выбирать `Qt`.* Тем более, что в промышленном плане библиотека очень качественная.

---

P.S *Насчет иксов можно вести отдельный разговор, но писать нативный интерфейс на них в наше время - достаточно глупая идея.*

Comment: "В GNOME: libcairo -> GTK"
А при чем тут libcairo?

Comment: @mikillskegg **Ну просто решил упомянуть**, т.к, если, например, нужно просто на `canvas'e` или в файл что-нибудь такое красивое с антиальясингом нарисовать *(или, скажем, быстро отрендерить `svg`), то `cairo` или `cairomm` могут быть предпочтительнее, нежели `Qt` там и прочие.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых утверждение "В MS Visual C++ есть Application" -- что-то из области бреда. Рекомендуется аспирин. Есть ряд библиотек классов, начиная с MFC, служащий надстройкой над win32api (не знаю, как в последних виндах), где есть объект Application.
Кроме Gtk и Qt (кстати многоплатформенные, должны быть и под "MS Visual C++") существует немало других библиотек. Программирование под X Windows с помощью библиотек "невысокого уровня" типа motif/lesstif значительно сложнее и требует наличия X server'а (что не проблема -- их есть). Кроме упомянутых Gtk и Qt навскидку wsWindows, Tcl/Tk (наиболее старый и в минимальном комплекте -- простой из существующих). Думаю, при желании можно найти ещё. Если вопрос касается построителей интерфейса для окошек/менюшек -- то их надо смотреть уже после выбора библиотеки виджетов. Они как правило присутствуют (и зачастую не в одном экземпляре) (1) и их необходимость неочевидна (2)

Answer (score -1):

glade. но с таким подходом к делу лутше и не начинай.

Comment: Чтоб пользоваться glade, нужно все равно знать gtk+

Comment: а какой должен быть подход?

Comment: Я отвечу. Если хочешь писать GUI под линь, будь готов к работе. Есть средства визуального программирования для gtk+, для Qt, для wxWidgets, но они призваны облегчать разработку, а не обучение. Чтобы их использовать, все равно нужно знать эти библиотеки. 

А glade вообще штука интересная...

Comment: Если есть желание писать GUI под винды -- то надо тоже быть готовым к работе. Иначе результат -- уродливый интерфейс (пользователей пугать). И таких примеров любой может привести много

Comment: Swing,GTK+,QT использую во всю идею layout т.е. менеджеров размещений. без понимания данной штуковины хорошего интерфейса не выйдет.